# Basic algorithm proof

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic

I have a sequence of numbers, for example: `170, 205, 225, 190, 260, 130, 225, 160` and I have to split them into sets with fixed number of elements so that the **maximal difference** between elements of the sets is **minimized**.

*I have a guarantee that if I need to split the elements into sets of `K` elements, then the global number of elements equals `Z * K`.*

*For the example with `K = 4`, the optimal splitting can be perfomed this way:*

`(1) : 130 160 170 190` *(max difference equals 60)*

`(2) : 205 225 225 260` *(max difference equals 55)*

So, the global max difference for this case equals 60.

---

Now, the question: is my assumption that I can **simply sort** the initial data and split it into even parts starting from the beginning? If this is correct, how can I *prove it?* And if it's not, which approach should I use to solve this problem?

Comment: I'm wondering if this might have a place on http://math.stackexchange.com/ - just sayin'

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that in the example, `K = 4` is given and you simply forgot to mention it?

Comment: @quasiverse Yes, that's correct.

Comment: @hamstergene This example is for `K = 4`, I updated the question.

Comment: Things get interesting, though, when the total number of items, `n`, isn't evenly divisible by `K`. Using your data and setting `K == 3`, your optimum arrangement is `[130, 160], [170, 190, 205], [225, 225, 260]`. The algorithm gets very messy when `n mod k != 0`.

Comment: This is slightly ambiguous.  I'm not sure if you want to minimize the sum of the maximum differences over all the buckets, or minimize the the largest bucket's difference.  There is a difference, since the first definition could sacrifice the size of one bucket to lessen the difference of several others.  I think you mean the second definition, but the first is more interesting!  :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your amount of numbers can always be divided exactly by K (so not 13 numbers in sets of 4), it is correct.

Through sorting, you get the most similar numbers as close to each other as possible, obviously. The question is, if numbers are moved to bring the worst placed value in a set with closer values, does that make the maximum difference smaller?

The answer is no. When sorted, the only values at the left of the of number are equal or lower, the number that would move to the left would be surrounded by lower values. Of the two numbers that caused the maximum difference, at least one would get an even worse partner, meaning your max distance would become higher. It works the same way with the higher numbers to the right.

```
Sorted:
[lowest, low, low, x] distance1 = x-lowest
[y, high, high, highest] distance2 = highest-y

Swapped:
[lowest, low, low, y] distance3 = y-lowest
[x, high, high, highest] distance4 = highest-x
```

Since x < y (let's assume they're not equal since swapping would be pointless), distance3 > distance1 and distance4 > distance2, meaning things got worse.

It works the same way if you place a higher value there.

No matter how off a number is, putting another number at that spot will make them more off.

Another option is to move the whole subset one space left:

```
[lowest, low, low, y]
[high, high, highest, x]
```

But this is actually the same result as swapping.

So that's how it works with 2 sets.

With three sets:

```
[lowest, low, low, x]
[lowM, lowM, highM, highM]
[highM, y, high, highest]
```

Swapping x and y is the same as earlier. Even if x is very similar or even equal to the bottom left high (if the middle lows and highs are actually equal), y is still higher than x, making the difference to lowest greater, and x is further away from highest.

Moving a bunch of numbers forwards:

```
[lowest, low, lowM, lowM]
[highM, highM, highM, y]
[x, highM, high, highest];
```

Perhaps the biggest difference was between highM and highest, and that distance is now removed. But since you can only move it away from highest by placing an even lower value there, you're always making it worse. The highest distance highest-highM is now highest-x, and x < highM.

It still works the other way round as well. Had there been a next set, highM could be swapped with a higher number closer to highest, but this would place highM with even higher numbers causing an even greater difference.

So yes, sorting the data and then splitting it in equal parts always gives you the minimal maximum difference, because changing the sorted sets always gives worse results.

Note: If the numbers are not dividable by K, it gets way more complicated, you'll have to figure out the worst set and see if you can move its highest or lowest number to a next or previous set without making another set a worse difference. The rule that you can only swap low numbers with high numbers is removed, since you can swap them with no-numbers, so proving things about that is a whole new level.

Answer (score 2):

If the initial sequence is sorted then the adjacent numbers must have the smallest   difference.

Moreover the elements in the beginning and the end of the sequence must have the largest  difference.

As a result any "cut" of the sequence that includes the last element and the first element can not be part of the solution since it includes a difference that in not the minimal.

So the split must be done by dividing the sequence of numbers into even parts starting from the beginnning.

It seems to me your approach is correct, but I can not think of a more formal proof for this.

Answer (score 0):

Naturally you will get the smallest difference between pairs of numbers by sorting them. You can get the sets with the smallest differences by simply splitting the sorted numbers.

<strike>In some cases you can switch numbers between sets without increasing the maximum of each set, so there can be more than one way of dividing the numbers into sets that gives the same maximum difference. However, you can't switch numbers between sets to decrease the maximum of either set without increasing the maximum of the other set.</strike>

If you for example have the sets `1,3,4,5` and `6,7,8,10`, then you can switch the `5` and `6` without increasing the maximum difference in either group.

If you would want the smallest *average* of the differences, then you could sacrifice the maximum difference in one set to decrease the difference in another set.

Comment: Sure the maximum in your example increases the max difference when switching: before switch the max difference is 10-6=4, afterwards it would be 10-5=5.

Comment: @flolo: Yes, you are right. I though of the difference between the closest numbers in the set, not between the smallest and largest in the set.